# Why is the same line appended on each successive file open?

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

My original .csv file has thousands of rows, but for clarity a single row is shown. I created 4 consecutive changes to the sample row. Python will make the correct changes, but append those changes. Instead of having a single row with all changes, I have 4 rows each representing a single change for each of the 4 changes.

I tried using `r`, `r+`, `w`, `a` modes and each essentially does the same. Tried using a single `print` statement. A single `print` statement saves a single row, but only 1 change.

```
import re

with open("orig.csv","r") as fi:
    contents=fi.readlines()

with open("output.csv","r+") as fi:
    for line in contents:
        fi = re.sub(r"<.*?>","",line)
        print(fi)

with open("orig.csv","r") as fi:
    contents=fi.readlines()
with open("output.csv","r+") as fi:
    for line in contents:
        fi=re.sub(r",[^,]+,Skipped,",",",line)
        print(fi)

with open("orig.csv","r") as fi:
    contents=fi.readlines()
with open("output.csv","r+") as fi:
    for line in contents:
        fi=re.sub(r",[^,]+,Done,",",",line)
        print(fi)

with open("orig.csv","r") as fi:
    contents=fi.readlines()

with open("output.csv","r+") as fi:
    for line in contents:
        fi=re.sub(r",,",",",line)
        print(fi)
```

My original data:

```
<UUT><H s='12' v='2.8'/>    <V t='s' s='2'/>Profile Debug   <V t='s' s='2'/>Cycle   Normal  <V t='s' s='2'/>PMVer   14.0.1.103  <V t='s' s='2'/>SeqFileVer  1.6.0.0 <V t='s' s='2'/>User    administrator   <V t='s' s='2'/>Station TS-0357A    <V t='s' s='2'/>Socket  0   <V t='s' s='2'/>Date    9/10/2018   <V t='s' s='2'/>Time    17:23:51    <V t='n' s='2'/>CycleTime   0   <V t='s' s='2'/>Status  Failed  <V t='s' s='2'/>MAC_Address f8dc7a128189    <R s='42'/> <S t='a' s='3'/>CycleTimes  Done<S t='a' s='3'/>DEBUG_PRODUCTION_FALSE  Skipped<S t='a' s='3'/>DEBUG_TROUBLESHOOTING_TRUE
```

Expected outcome:

```
,Profile,Debug,Cycle,Normal,PMVer,14.0.1.103,SeqFileVer,1.6.0.0,User,administrator,Station,TS-0357A,Socket,0,Date,9/10/2018,Time,17:23:51,CycleTime,0,Status,Failed,MAC_Address,f8dc7a128189,CycleTimes,DEBUG_TROUBLESHOOTING_TRUE
```

Comment: I don't see any commas in the original data. Shouldn't you be using csv for parsing a csv file?

Comment: maybe you shoud use only one `for` loop, read line only once and make all changes in this line and then print it only once. Your code never write it back to file so you always get the same unchanged line from file.

Comment: you use `fi` as pointer to file so don't assing result from `re` to this variable because this way you don't have access to file. Better assing back to `line` - `line  = re.sub(r",[^,]+,Skipped,",",",line)` `line = re.sub(...another..., line)`. And use `fi.write(line)` to write to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only one `for`-loop and read line only once and use all `re.sub` on this line before you write it in file

```
import re

with open("orig.csv", "r") as file_in:
    contents = file_in.readlines()

with open("output.csv", "w") as file_out:
    for line in contents:
        line = re.sub(r"<.*?>", "", line)
        line = re.sub(r",[^,]+,Skipped,", ",", line)
        line = re.sub(r",[^,]+,Done,", ",", line)
        line = re.sub(r",,", ",", line)
        line = re.sub(r"\s+", ",", line) # remove spaces

        file_out.write(line) # write in file

        print(line) # display on screen
```

---

Example which everyone can easily copy and test

```
import re

data = "<UUT><H s='12' v='2.8'/>    <V t='s' s='2'/>Profile Debug   <V t='s' s='2'/>Cycle   Normal  <V t='s' s='2'/>PMVer   14.0.1.103  <V t='s' s='2'/>SeqFileVer  1.6.0.0 <V t='s' s='2'/>User    administrator   <V t='s' s='2'/>Station TS-0357A    <V t='s' s='2'/>Socket  0   <V t='s' s='2'/>Date    9/10/2018   <V t='s' s='2'/>Time    17:23:51    <V t='n' s='2'/>CycleTime   0   <V t='s' s='2'/>Status  Failed  <V t='s' s='2'/>MAC_Address f8dc7a128189    <R s='42'/> <S t='a' s='3'/>CycleTimes  Done<S t='a' s='3'/>DEBUG_PRODUCTION_FALSE  Skipped<S t='a' s='3'/>DEBUG_TROUBLESHOOTING_TRUE"
contents = data.split('\n')

with open("output.csv", "w") as file_out:
    for line in contents:
        line = re.sub(r"<.*?>", "", line)
        line = re.sub(r",[^,]+,Skipped,", ",", line)
        line = re.sub(r",[^,]+,Done,", ",", line)
        line = re.sub(r",,", ",", line)
        line = re.sub(r"\s+", ",", line) # remove spaces
        file_out.write(line)
        print(line)
```

Comment: Your python corrections are the 95% answer. If I open the csv file as is the data appears on a single row. if I redirect it project.py > output.csv the data fills the file on a different row when opened in Excel.

Comment: maybe you have to set `,` as separator when you open in Excel or maybe you have to use `;` instead of `,` in code.